# Is there a way to force a boxplot graph to show all numbers in a continuous scale when the max data doesn't reach that high in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to graph some data and will be making multiple box plots. As well as being able to visually compare within a boxplot, I want it to be easy to visually compare boxplots when they are next to eachother and so want all the graphs to have the same y limit (0-500), even though the data for some of these graphs will only go up to ~400. By using the code below I produce the graph below. You can see even though I have put the max at 500 for breaks it cuts off the actual graphing at 440, but I would like to  force it to go to 500. How do I go about doing this?

`ggplot(twohour, aes(x = Treatment, y = Total, fill = Treatment)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(0), max(500), by = 20),1)) + geom_boxplot()`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enforce the range of your plot to be between 0 and 500 with the `limits` argument so that your code will work. Additionally, min(), max() and round() are not necessary in your context :

```
ggplot(twohour, aes(x = Treatment, y = Total, fill = Treatment)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,500),
                     breaks = seq(0, 500, by = 20)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```